# Isomorphsim: Prove that $\varphi(C(a)) = C(\varphi(a))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\varphi:G\to\overline G$ be an isomorphism from a group $G$ to a group $\overline G$ and let $a$ belong to $G$. Prove that $\varphi(C(a)) = C(\varphi(a))$, where $C$ denotes centralizer.

Comment: By $C$, you mean the centralizer? What have you tried? There is not really any trick here, just apply the definitions.

Comment: That is what I am confused by. It just says C. Centralizer was never defined in this chapter.

Comment: There is not really any way for us to guess what is meant by a piece of notation with no further information than this.

Comment: I read further. It is centralizer. My apologies.

Comment: So this leads us back to the "what have you tried?" part.

Comment: I got this now. I just didn't read far enough. Thank you.

Comment: Does that mean you figured out the answer to your question? Feel free to write up your own solution, or select Alexander's answer by checking the green checkmark near his answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* If $a=b^{-1}ab$, then $\varphi(a)=\varphi(b^{-1}ab)=\varphi(b^{-1})\varphi(a)\varphi(b)=\varphi(b)^{-1}\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$.  This gives you one of the directions: why?  Can you construct a similar argument for the opposite conclusion using $\varphi^{-1}:\overline{G}\rightarrow G$? (and why must $\varphi^{-1}$ exist?)